# Count and Print from an range

Tags: vba, excel

I have an array of data, a screenshot of it will be linked at the bottom of this text. Row and column references are to the screenshot.

I am trying to write a macro that will output all the dates that **occur** within the dynamic range (Column H). And then in column I I want the column **header** @ **row** i.e I4.

But if there is more than 1 count at the date, I would like the second school to output into column J. As it would for the date 26/03/18, looking like this:

h5 = 26/03/18 , i5(Event1) = Task 2 @ 1, j5(Event2) = task 2 @ 4

I have tried many ways today and would like some assistance.

Screenshot: https://ibb.co/cmiGSc

My Code thus far(For the more complex sheet):

```
Sub Events()
'How many schools there are
Dim sh As Worksheet
' This needs to change for each sheets
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Easter 18")
Dim k As Long

k = sh.Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row 'Counts up from bottow - Number of schools attained
Ro = Range("M52").value = k - 2 'Elimiates the two top rows as headers

'Now I need to search the Range of dates
Dim TaskDates As Range
Dim StartCell  As Range 'First part of Array
Dim EndCell As Range 'End of Array
Set EndCell = Range("J" & 2 + k) 'maybe 2 or 3
Set StartCell = Range("G3")
Set TaskDates = Range(StartCell, EndCell) 'Dynamic Range

'Within the range of data print out the most left row header (school name) - and task with @ in the middle - ascending
' If Column has date (true) create a table with Date (col 1), Event (col 2), Event 2 (Col3) etc etc
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Dim varray As Variant, element As Variant
varray = TaskDates.value

'Generate unique list and count
For Each element In varray
If dict.exists(element) Then
    dict.item(element) = dict.item(element) + 1
   Else
    dict.Add element, 1
   End If
Next

   'Paste report somewhere -
   'First line ouptuts the dates occured
   sh.Range("M55").Resize(dict.Count).value =     'Was working now saying syntax error for this line. 
       WorksheetFunction.Transpose (dict.keys)
   ' The count works if cell format is correct
   CDates = sh.Range("N55").Resize(dict.Count, 1).value = _
       WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.items)
End Sub
```

Please feel free to redesign it if you see fit.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: What if there is more than 3 occurences of the date? Also what's the difference between `n/a` and a blank space? Like what would you do for 13/04/2018, which occurs 4 times?

Comment: @SJR - While I have the count output from the dictionary function, I would like to identify the cell so then I can print out the corresponding column header @ the row identifier, as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: @dwirony - Nothing, i just whipped up a basic one to show, I will amend it so they are all blank. And if the the date appears four times, as you have stated, i would like then to put put into the next columns, so k and l in the screenshot.

Comment: @Infernez If it appears 4 times then it would be in I, J, K and L then, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can go this way

```
Option Explicit

Sub Tasks()
    Dim cell As Range, f As Range

    With Worksheets("schools") 'change "schools" to your actual sheet name
        For Each cell In .Range("C4:F" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row) 'reference its column C:F from row 4 down to column B last not empty cell
            If IsDate(cell.value) Then 'if current cell value is a valid date
                Set f = .Range("H3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp)).Find(what:=cell.value, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) 'try finding the date in column H
                If f Is Nothing Then Set f = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Offset(1) 'if date not already in column H then get its first empty cell after last not empty one 
                f.value = cell.value 'write the date (this is sometimes not necessary, but not to "ruin" the code)
                .Cells(f.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).value = .Cells(3, cell.Column).value & " @" & .Cells(cell.Row, 2).value ' write the record in the first not empty cell in the "date" row
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @ Displayname - I shall try this function now and report back.

Comment: @Infernez, What I meant in my other post comment is that you are supposed to select answers that solve your questions (if any) and mark them as accepted (you can accept one solution per question). Or you may upvote it if it was useful although wasn't the accepted one. Or you may do nothing, if any of those apply. But from your comments here and there I feel that you should accept and/or upvote many of the answers you received.

Comment: Not enough 'rep' to up vote yet, otherwise I would have.

Comment: Well, giving feedback is one of the ways to gain rep. As for this question, may I ask why did you choose the other answer?

Comment: It was in a language I understood better than yours, and I need to resolve the solution pronto. I will try your solution properly when I have more time.

Comment: I see. Well when you'll get there consider that loops and If-Then-Else are things you want to limit (if not avoid) for the sake of code speed and maintenance so: 1 loop is (much) better than three nested loops and 2 simple "If-Then-End If" are (much) better than 4 to 5 nested "IF-Then-ElseiF-End IF". And, from a maintenance point of view again, a 10 lines code is (much) better than  a 40 lines one...

Answer (score 0):

Took a shot at this. Just a couple nested loops testing against the dates, making sure that the date found isn't already listed under the date column. As I stated before, you never said what to do if more than 3 dates are found, so I had to add a fourth event column and assume that that's the max. Anything more than 4 dates won't be recorded anywhere, FYI.

```
Sub MoveDates()

Dim i As Long, j As Long, sht As Worksheet, lastrow As Long, lastrow2 As Long, refrow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row + 1

For i = 4 To lastrow
    For j = 3 To 6
        If Cells(i, j).Value <> "" And Cells(i, j).Value <> "n/a" Then
            If Not Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H4:H" & lastrow), Cells(i, j)) > 0 Then
                lastrow2 = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                Range("H" & lastrow2).Value = Cells(i, j).Value

                If Range("I" & lastrow2).Value = "" Then
                    Range("I" & lastrow2).Value = Cells(3, j).Value & " @ " & Cells(i, 2).Value
                ElseIf Range("J" & lastrow2).Value = "" Then
                    Range("J" & lastrow2).Value = Cells(3, j).Value & " @ " & Cells(i, 2).Value
                ElseIf Range("K" & lastrow2).Value = "" Then
                    Range("K" & lastrow2).Value = Cells(3, j).Value & " @ " & Cells(i, 2).Value
                ElseIf Range("L" & lastrow2).Value = "" Then
                    Range("L" & lastrow2).Value = Cells(3, j).Value & " @ " & Cells(i, 2).Value
                End If

            Else
                lastrow2 = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

                For k = 4 To lastrow2
                    If Range("H" & k).Value = Cells(i, j).Value Then
                        refrow = k
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next k

                If Range("I" & refrow).Value = "" Then
                    Range("I" & refrow).Value = Cells(3, j).Value & " @ " & Cells(i, 2).Value
                ElseIf Range("J" & refrow).Value = "" Then
                    Range("J" & refrow).Value = Cells(3, j).Value & " @ " & Cells(i, 2).Value
                ElseIf Range("K" & refrow).Value = "" Then
                    Range("K" & refrow).Value = Cells(3, j).Value & " @ " & Cells(i, 2).Value
                ElseIf Range("L" & refrow).Value = "" Then
                    Range("L" & refrow).Value = Cells(3, j).Value & " @ " & Cells(i, 2).Value
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

[image: Before After]

Comment: That is perfect. 

Thank you.

Just one thing, How would I make the outputs ascend from earliest date to the latest date, in the VBA code.

Additionally if I had 5 events, Do i just add the next column along to your code?